# a%&8b is valid variable name or not in BASIC

Tags: vb6, basic

a%&8b is valid variable name basic
Suggest me if it is valid in VB6

Help me. It is  my exams

Comment: [This](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/vba-variables/) is for Vba, but applies to VB6 too. The official VB6 documeantation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6.0-documentation).

Answer (score 1):

`a%&8b` is NOT a valid name.  Specifically, you cannot have `&` and `%` in the name.

The [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/visual-basic-naming-rules) for VBA are:

- You must use a letter as the first character.
- You can't use a space, period (.), exclamation mark (!), or the characters @, &, $, # in the name.
- Name can't exceed 255 characters in length.

[Another source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/The_Language) on VB6 lists the following:

> Variable names in Visual Basic are made up of letters (upper and lower case) and digits. The underscore character, "_", is also permitted. Names must not begin with a digit. Names can be as long as you like.

Some examples of valid (but not very descriptive) Visual Basic variable names:

```
 foo
 Bar
 BAZ
 foo_bar
 a_foo42_
 QuUx
```

Some examples of invalid Visual Basic variable names:

`2foo`
must not begin with a digit
`my foo`
spaces not allowed in names
`$foo`
$ not allowed -- only letters, digits, and _
`while`
language keywords cannot be used as names
`_xxx`
leading underscore not allowed.

Comment: To add to that: the VB6 help _(MSDN Library October 2001)_ states: "A variable name must begin with a letter, can't contain an embedded period or embedded type-declaration character, Must not exceed 255 characters, must be unique within the same scope, which is the range from which the variable can be referenced — a procedure, a form, and so on."

Comment: `F00$` is allowed. `Dim Foo$:Foo$ = "Cat":MsgBox Foo$ & Foo`

Comment: @Lundt Does not work in my Visual Basic 6 Studio.  `Foo` works fine but `Foo$` gives me an immediate error.  Same for `F00$` and for `F00`.

Comment: I copied it from VB6. So you typed it wrong.

Comment: Interesting that `Dim Foo$:Foo$ = "Cat":MsgBox Foo$ & Foo` does seem to work but not `Dim Foo$ As String`.  I wonder if there is an issue with Visual Studio 6.

Comment: No you have Option Explicit turned on. Turn it off. See https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/191/Q191713/

Comment: EG In WordBasic (Microsoft Word 1 and 2) there is no `as` in the `dim` statement. It is `Dim MyString$` as a string or `Dim MyNum` as a number.

Comment: This is interesting.  I never knew this.  `Dim Foo$` is the same as `Dim Foo As String` so you cannot have `Dim Foo$ As String` because it becomes `Dim Foo As String As String`.  It does work event with `Option Explicit`.  Very interesting.  Good job.